# How to set up a chinese made game controller in windows 8

Tags: technical-issues, controllers

I have a chinese made usb game controller with me that I bought in Delhi. In the shop it worked in windows 7. But when I tried it on my Sony Vaio laptop, it is not working.

In the devices section in control panel it shows up as USB Joystick. But when I try to setup the game controller using [this method](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-USB-Game-Controllers-on-Windows-8), it does not show up at all.

Fifa 13 settings also do not show the controller. I have no idea what to do about it.

The manufacturer of the  controller is unknown. It just says SC on it. It looks like a standard game controller like this:

[image: image of controller]

I would appreciate any help in this matter.

Comment: Did you get any drivers with it?  Does it do anything in Windows at all?

Comment: `I have a chinese made usb game controller`. Most devices are "Made in China" nowadays, even the popular *Xbox 360* and the *Dualshock 4* (PS4) game constrollers. To be honest, the controller in question looks like it's supposed to work with the PS2; are you sure it's even compatible to Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 and/or FIFA 13 may be expecting an Xbox 360 compatible controller.  You may need to use an emulator such as [XBOX 360CE](https://code.google.com/p/x360ce/) in order to get it working.